# Invalid Image - For iOS applications, icons included in the binary submission must be in the PNG format

Tags: ios, iphone, image, app-store-connect

Every time i have tried to upload my app, i keep getting the following response from apple:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "app name". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct
>   the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Invalid Image - For iOS applications, icons included in the binary
>   submission must be in the PNG format.
>
> If your application supports the iPhone device family, you must
>   include square icons of the following dimensions: 57x57 pixels and
>   120x120 pixels. If your application supports the iPad device family,
>   you must include square icons of the following dimensions: 72x72
>   pixels, 76x76 pixels and 152x152 pixels For Mac OS X applications,
>   icons included in the binary submission must be in the ICNS format and
>   must include a square 512x512@2x image. If you would like to update
>   your binary for this app, you can reject this binary from the Binary
>   Details page in iTunes Connect. Note that rejecting your binary will
>   remove your app from the review queue and the review process will
>   start over from the beginning when you resubmit your binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

I don't understand whats wrong with it, yesterday there was a problem with itunes connect and it keeps timing out and now this.

I have checked my icon images and they all seem to be the correct size!

I have also added more brightness to my image but still nothing.

Any one know what to do?

Comment: Have you checked that the images are in the PNG format? Make sure that they are not just renamed to PN but are really in the PNG format.

Comment: I have just checked all of the images that are contained in my app. All of which are PNG files. Its so strange because the app is a update. I haven't had this problem the last few times i have uploaded the app. @rckoenes

Comment: I got the same email. My submission is an update as well, with no changes to the icons whatsoever. And it just got approved. I'm guessing it's something to do with the recent iTunesConnect problems?

Comment: @bmueller I uploaded 2 apps today got the same email for both apps. Thank you for letting me know that it isn't just me. It must be with the recent mishap they had. They should inform every one if they're having issues still. Thank you though.

Comment: @bmueller - are you saying you received the message, did nothing, and your app update got approved?  The message from Apple makes it sound like adding the 120x120 is optional at this time.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yep, I received the message, did nothing, the update got approved, and everything was fine with the update once it appeared in the App Store.

Comment: @bmueller thank you for letting me know i have been worrying all weekend.

Comment: My app got approved regardless to the email that they sent. A Few people have mentioned that it could be to do with iOS7 which I also believe now that that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We update our app a couple days ago. And we receive the same email, i did a couple of google searches. I Found out that email could be related to ios7 release. since the old ios6 icons are 114x114 for iphone and 144x144 for ipad. Now apple is basically asking us to change the size of our icons to 120x120 for iphone and 152x152 for ipad. I could be wrong, but i am pretty convinced that's something related to ios7 which maybe released in a couple of weeks.

Hope this will help ...

Answer (score 0):

In previous iOS versions, we not need to upload 120x120 icon for iPhone but in iOS7, we also need to upload 120x120 icon; Hope, it will resolve the issue;